# How do I get a list of closed indexes in ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I recently closed an index via the Head plugin in Elasticsearch.
I did NOT delete it.

I want to re-open it, but god forbid I forget which index I closed.

How do get a list of all the indexes that I closed?

I tried:

```
curl -s localhost:9200/_stats  | grep logstash-2013.12.05
curl -s localhost:9200/_status | grep logstash-2013.12.05
```

But no luck.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When asking for:
/_cluster/state/metadata

You get a list of indices, from each index you can request the state:
metadata.indices["your_index"].state

I use this in my plugin as well and it works for me:
http://www.gridshore.nl/esgui/

Comment: This works great but the size of the response can be prohibitively big. It contains for each index all of its metadata. settings and mappings included.

I am using `/_cluster/state/blocks` as suggested by @grayaii.
Then use the `/_cat/indices` API to list the other non-closed indices.

Answer (score 12):

You can use this:

```
http://yourserver:9200/_cluster/state/blocks?pretty
```

it would have been nice for Elasticsearch to stick it on this page: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-open-close.html

Comment: Its best if you post the relevant data from the linked page.  That way its not lost if the link changes.  It also looks like you were responding to another users post... When you have more rep, you can add these as comments...

Answer (score 8):

Since Elasticsearch 5 you can sort the catalog output

```
GET /_cat/indices?v&s=status:asc
```

Would give you
[image]

Answer (score 4):

So far, there is no any API to do this. But you can write a script to determine which index is closed.

Checking API:

```
    curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/_cluster/health/logstash-2014.02.21?pretty
```

Here is the status of index

Index Opened:

```
{
     "cluster_name" : "ABC",
     "status" : "green",
     "timed_out" : false,
     "number_of_nodes" : 1,
     "number_of_data_nodes" : 1,
     "active_primary_shards" : 1,
     "active_shards" : 1,
     "relocating_shards" : 0,
     "initializing_shards" : 0,
     "unassigned_shards" : 0
}
```

Index Closed:

```
{
    "cluster_name" : "ABC",
    "status" : "green",
    "timed_out" : false,
    "number_of_nodes" : 1,
    "number_of_data_nodes" : 1,
    "active_primary_shards" : 0,
    "active_shards" : 0,
    "relocating_shards" : 0,
    "initializing_shards" : 0,
    "unassigned_shards" : 0
}
```

From the information you can determine the index status by **active_primary_shards**.
Hope this can help you.

Comment: I see my closed node listed under the "blocks" section in cluster/health, but I can't find in the documentation what "blocks" even means.

Answer (score 2):

Adding a command that prints the list of closed indices (and nothing else), wich I was googling for.

```
curl -s -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_cat/indices?h=status,index' | awk '$1 == "close" {print $2}'
```

- `-s` will silence the curl, so it doesn't show status bar
- `h=status,index` param says the `_cat` command to print only the two columns
- the `awk` filter will print index names when status is *close*

See also: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/cat-indices.html

---

Apparently newer version of the `_cat` command is more powerful.. sorting, filtering, you name it. See:  https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cat-indices.html

Answer (score 2):

```
http://es_endpoints.com:9200/index-pattern-*/_settings?expand_wildcards=closed
```

Get the answer from IndicesOptions.java from ES source code:

```
public static IndicesOptions fromParameters(Object wildcardsString, Object ignoreUnavailableString, Object allowNoIndicesString, IndicesOptions defaultSettings) {
    if (wildcardsString == null && ignoreUnavailableString == null && allowNoIndicesString == null) {
        return defaultSettings;
    }

    boolean expandWildcardsOpen = false;
    boolean expandWildcardsClosed = false;
    if (wildcardsString == null) {
        expandWildcardsOpen = defaultSettings.expandWildcardsOpen();
        expandWildcardsClosed = defaultSettings.expandWildcardsClosed();
    } else {
        String[] wildcards = nodeStringArrayValue(wildcardsString);
        for (String wildcard : wildcards) {
            if ("open".equals(wildcard)) {
                expandWildcardsOpen = true;
            } else if ("closed".equals(wildcard)) {
                expandWildcardsClosed = true;
            } else if ("none".equals(wildcard)) {
                expandWildcardsOpen = false;
                expandWildcardsClosed = false;
            } else if ("all".equals(wildcard)) {
                expandWildcardsOpen = true;
                expandWildcardsClosed = true;
            } else {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("No valid expand wildcard value [" + wildcard + "]");
            }
        }
    }

    //note that allowAliasesToMultipleIndices is not exposed, always true (only for internal use)
    return fromOptions(
            nodeBooleanValue(ignoreUnavailableString, "ignore_unavailable", defaultSettings.ignoreUnavailable()),
            nodeBooleanValue(allowNoIndicesString, "allow_no_indices", defaultSettings.allowNoIndices()),
            expandWildcardsOpen,
            expandWildcardsClosed,
            defaultSettings.allowAliasesToMultipleIndices(),
            defaultSettings.forbidClosedIndices(),
            defaultSettings.ignoreAliases()
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the only question for you here is just seeing which index is closed, i.e. the administrative task you can use e.g. ElasticSearh head plugin:

```
http://yourserver:9200/_plugin/head/
```

Don't forget the last slash. If you can not install it (e.g. on some hosted ElasticSearch), or can't use it for other reason, or want to manipulate indices programmatically, you can use other advices here to find it out using API.

P.S.:  /_cluster/state/metadata really can be very-very long e.g. if you are using dynamic mapping.

Answer (score 1):

Use Curl GET _cat/indices, $2 would show the state of your index.

Comment: An open index will have "green open" - status in $1, state in $2, while a closed index has "close" in $1 (whitespace in the status field ). `curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/_cat/indices | sort | less` - or even `curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/_cat/indices | awk '$1=="close"'`